# How to use HTTPS through a web proxy in nodejs

Tags: proxy, node.js, https

I can do this with HTTP:

```
var http = require ('http');

http.get ({
    host: 'my.proxy.com',
    port: 8080,
    path: 'http://nodejs.org/'
}, function (response) {
    console.log (response);
});
```

But if I want to go to an HTTPS resource, it doesn't work.

Do I have to use the HTTP connect method or something?  How would I structure this?

thanks!

Comment: Questions and answers like these are bad. Problem is far too vague. Answers are far too localized at sub sets of the problem. [You have read the HTTPS docs right?](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.7/api/https.html)

Comment: How is this vague or the answer localized? If the problem is that he is using the `http` module instead of the `https` module, that is a likely to be repeated problem with a simple and universal solution.

Comment: I have the same issue here...node https not working behind firewall...Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
var https = require('https');
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Http is generally port 80, while https is generally port 443. Have you set the server to respond to https requests on port 8080?

Comment: yeah, i'm sure. my browser uses the same proxy for http and https.  i think that browsers use the CONNECT instruction, which i don't think is supported in node, so i may be out of luck here...